# munin not showing any of the graphs

Tags: linux, monitoring, munin

I have deployed the munin, but the its not displaying any of the graphs. I am not able to understand whats wrong with the configuration. Initially it used to show some graphs but not the stats, it was just a blank graph. Help to fix this issue.

Thnaks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having experienced a plethora of fun gotchas with munin myself, there's several things that can cause that problem.

Off the top of my head:

- The user running the munin cronjobs doesnt have permission to write to the graphs folder.
- munin-node isn't running
- Improper configuration. Make sure all the addresses/ports are correct in munin.conf and munin-node.conf